# How do I change my azurewebsites.net subdomain

Tags: azure, configuration, subdomain

Currently my domain is domain1.azurewebsites.net. I want to change it to domain2.azurewebsites.net

I have looked through the various configuration screens on the portal but cannot find an 'edit name' area. Can anyone advise me on the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Delete your web app and re-deploy with a new name...

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain is the same as the name of your App Service. Once you create an App Service. 
Azure automatically assign this to App Service and you cannot change it.

So you have to create a new app service if you want to change the subdomain.

Note: If you have a custom domain, you can map it. [More Details...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)